# Проблема со scan в dynamodb

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

Пытаюсь сделать scan в dynamodb, с использованием PHP и пакета aws/aws-sdk-php
Мне нужно найти непрочитанные уведомления для определенных аккаунтов. Кроме того, уведомления должны быть определнных типов. Аккаунтов и типов может быть несколько.

Вот как я пытаюсь это делать на PHP

```
public function getUnreadNotifications($accountIds): array
    {
        $expressionValues = $this->marshaler->marshalItem([
            ':readStatus' => Notification::STATUS_NOT_READ
        ]);

        $params = [
            'FilterExpression' => 'read_status = :readStatus'
        ];

        /**
         * Добавляем выборку по типу
         */
        $typeKeys = [];
        foreach (Notification::TYPES as $typeIndex => $type) {
            $typeKeys[':type_' . $typeIndex] = $this->marshaler->marshalValue($type);
        }

        $accountIdKeys = [];

        foreach ($accountIds as $accountIdIndex => $accountId) {
            $accountIdKeys[':account_id_' . $accountIdIndex] = $this->marshaler->marshalValue($accountId);
        }

        $expressionValues = array_merge($expressionValues, $typeKeys, $accountIdKeys);

        $params['FilterExpression'] .= sprintf(' and #type IN (%s) and #account_id IN (%s)',
            implode(',', array_keys($typeKeys)),
            implode(',', array_keys($accountIdKeys))
        );

        $params['ExpressionAttributeNames'] = [
            '#type' => 'type',
            '#account_id' => 'account_id',
        ];


        $params = array_merge($params, [
            'TableName' => $this->getTableName(),
            'ExpressionAttributeValues' => $expressionValues,
        ]);

        return $this->scan($params);
    }
```

Однако в результате получаю пустой массив например для моего аккаунта

При этом запрос из консоли к dynamodb работает как надо

`/usr/local/bin/aws dynamodb scan --table-name Notifications --expression-attribute-values '{":account_id_0":{"N":"15"}, ":readStatus":{"N":"0"}, ":type_0":{"S":"account_document_verified"}, ":type_1":{"S":"card_payment"}}' --expression-attribute-names '{"#type":"type", "#account_id":"account_id"}' --filter-expression "read_status = :readStatus and #type IN (:type_0,:type_1) and #account_id IN (:account_id_0)" --endpoint=http://localhost:8000`

Как выглядит при этом массив `$params` с параметрами для dynamodb из примера кода

```
  'FilterExpression' =>
  string(78) "read_status = :readStatus and #type IN (:type_0,:type_1) and #account_id IN ()"
  'ExpressionAttributeNames' =>
  array(2) {
    '#type' =>
    string(4) "type"
    '#account_id' =>
    string(10) "account_id"
  }
  'TableName' =>
  string(13) "Notifications"
  'ExpressionAttributeValues' =>
  array(3) {
    ':readStatus' =>
    array(1) {
      'N' =>
      string(1) "0"
    }
    ':type_0' =>
    array(1) {
      'S' =>
      string(25) "account_document_verified"
    }
    ':type_1' =>
    array(1) {
      'S' =>
      string(12) "card_payment"
    }
  }
}
```

Что я делаю не так? Ведь то, что я составил на PHP по идее идентично чистому запросу.

Answer (score 0):

Правильный ответ: нужно было сканировать таблицу с использованием LastEvaluatedKey